# python 3 pillow

Tags: python-3.x, pillow, gif

как сделать 0 повторений в gif, код:

```
s1.save('test.gif',
        append_images=images,
        loop=0,
        duration=100,
        save_all=True)
```

Comment: `loop=1` что ли?

Comment: @andreymal, нет так не работает я пробовал, gif два раза повторяется